# Are there post-doc grants available for non-US citizens in the US?

Tags: funding, postdocs, united-states

I was looking for postdoctoral grants/fellowships for a potential post-doc opportunity in the US. It appears as the entire grant/fellowship system is geared towards US citizens, or permanent residents of the US. It is understandable with respect to use of federal resources, but slightly discouraging nevertheless.

Are there any funding opportunities available for non-US citizen? In terms of field I'm interested specifically in Biomedical and STEM fieds.

Comment: Of course. Look for open postdoc positions in academic projects funded by NSF and the like.

Comment: @DCTLib are you sure? I have just look at the [NSF post-doc grants](http://www.nsf.gov/funding/education.jsp?fund_type=3) and the solicitation documents clearly state that applicants must be US citizens or permanent residents by the time of applicaton

Comment: Related: [Can individual international scholars apply for US federal funds?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/21618/4140) and [Is there any funding opportunity for postdoc in US?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/43671/4140) and [Research grants for international PhD candidates](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/17320/4140).

Comment: @posdef On advertised open postdoc positions, you become postdoc in the research group of your future postdoc advisor who applied for the funding in the past and already got it granted.

Comment: @DCTLib Sure, I'm with you on that one. But if you want to be able to bring your own money in then you are out of luck, right?

Comment: @posdef You could always bring money from your home country, where you could apply for funding for a research project to be performed abroad. You will still be likely to need support from a host professor before you can apply, though.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is relatively little funding of the sort you are looking for--funding that non-U.S. residents can apply for directly to fund post-doctoral work inside the U.S.  However, that is not really that important, since that is not how most post-doc positions are funded anyway.

Most post-docs do not apply for their own funding.  The funding comes from the institution that hires the post-doc (Very often--but not always--the money ultimately comes from a research grant from an outside agency, but the post-doc would not be involved in writing or administering the grant.)  If an institution has funds for a post-doc, they will advertise a job opening and hire somebody.  Generally, the search is global; they would be willing to hire somebody from anywhere in the world, provided they are a qualified.  (There are some technical caveats about how this works, but they are of little import in practice; and--again--they are things that the hiring institution mostly needs to worry about, not the person they choose to hire.)

Answer (score 2):

I think in some fields, grants like  [Human Frontier Science Program](http://www.hfsp.org/)  and [Life Sciences Research Foundation](http://www.lsrf.org/home)  are helpful especially biology.
However, competition is very high in these and profile has to be in the top 5-10 of the applicants.